# question about the find() function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie to python. During an exercise I tried to run the following code:

```
def my_find(haystack,needle):
    for index,letter in enumerate(haystack):
        if letter==needle:
            return index
        return -1
print(my_find("banana","a"))
```

The result is -1, which is not what I expected. How can I make it work properly?

Comment: Your `return -1` needs to be less indented.

Comment: write `return -1` outside of for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And use this if you want to find all needles and get it returned as a list:

```
def my_find(haystack,needle):
    matches=[]
    for index,letter in enumerate(haystack):
        if letter==needle:
            matches.append(index)
    return matches
```

In the comments it was rightly pointed out that the second return statement was in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

please return the value outside for loop

```
def my_find(haystack,needle):
    for index,letter in enumerate(haystack):
        if letter==needle:
            return index
    return -1
print(my_find("banana","a"))
```

Comment: thank you!  haven't thought it was an indent problem

Answer (score 0):

The correct code should be -

```
def my_find(haystack,needle):
    for index,letter in enumerate(haystack):
        if letter==needle:
            return index
    return -1
print(my_find("banana","a"))
```

return should be outside the "for" block.